# How to apply DI on methods in nested classes

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm trying to refactor some old code in order to implement (make use of) the dependency injection pattern.

How do I correctly new up a class, inside a different class method?

Given to following minimal example:

```cs
class Select {
    List<Where> Wheres = new List<Where>();

    public Select()
    {
    }

    public Select Where(string field, string condition, object value) 
    {
        this.Wheres.Add(new Where(field, condition)); //How to resolve this?
        return this;
    }

    public object DoSomething() 
    {
        //...
    }

}

class Where {
    string _Field;
    string _Condition;
    object _value;

    public Where(string field, string condition, object value)
    {
        _Field = field;
        _Condition = condition;
        _value = value;
    }

    public object DoSomething() 
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Is it best practice to call Resovle() inside the Where-Method?
Or should I consider a completely different approach?

Comment: Have you tried methods like "Resolve" in your DI?

Comment: What you are trying to resolve? The `Where` implementation you'd hide behind a `IWhere` interface? Or rather, you'd want a container to automatically create an instance but it's always the concrete `Where`?

Comment: Do you have the opportunity to refactor to interfaces and register the instances with AutoFac?  Then you can require the interface in your class ctor, or worse encapsulate resolving in some other method (i.e. Init()).

Comment: @Kamushek Yes. My Question was rat
her if I can put the "Resolve"-Call inside my "public Select Where(string field, string condition, object value)"-Method.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Yes, I would hide it behind an Interface.

Comment: @StinkyTowel I can refactor. But the Select-Class **can** have multiple instances of the Where-Class

Comment: @FlyingDutchman: while you could make the container responsible for actual resolution, it doesn't solve the issue because you still have to have the container available. For an example solution, follow my [tutorial](https://www.wiktorzychla.com/2012/12/di-factories-and-composition-root.html) and its [follow up](https://www.wiktorzychla.com/2016/01/di-factories-and-composition-root.html).

Comment: Why have a method of _Select_ that returns an updated instance of _Select_ based on the method _Where_?  Why not make _Wheres_ readonly and have the _Where_ method **void** and have it operate on/update the readonly List?

Comment: @WiktorZychla Will read your post tonight, but it looks good.

Comment: @StinkyTowel It's just an example, no real implementation. By returning the current Select, I'm would be able to do stuff like "Select().Where( x = 1).Where(y = 2)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling a bit further in this topic, I found this thread on StackExchange:
[Link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/346949/how-do-i-support-per-method-call-instantiation-without-referencing-the-ioc-conta).

So basically, Autofac (or many other IoC) is able to automatically implement a factory, which can be passed as a Func.
The answer on StackExchange provides 3 links with code examples for Autofac, Ninject and Castle Windsor.